# Does iOS always restart the app when the system locale changes?

Tags: flutter, localization, internationalization

I am implementing i18n. I'd like the app to reflect changes to the system locale (aka user changing the locale in the system settings).
This works with [i18n_extensions](https://pub.dev/packages/i18n_extension) on Android, my app's state is kept and the translations are refreshing, but on iPhone simulator, if I switch back to the app after a change in the system locale, the app restarts, as if I was doing some [flutter_phoenix](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phoenix) or other `MaterialApp` rebuild shenanigans.

I'd like to also have my app's state kept on iOS, surviving locale changes. Is this possible?